# How to expand & stringify such macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm making a wrapper for the string parser, which converts string to primitive types. I'm writing unit tests for it, so I need the string representation of the extreme values of these primitive types, so it is needed to stringify the standard macros such as INT_MIN and INT_MAX.

The normal stringify macros look like this:

```
#define STRINGIFY(content) #content
#define EXPAND_AND_STRINGIFY(input) STRINGIFY(input)
```

It works well for `EXPAND_AND_STRINGIFY(SHRT_MAX)`, which will be expanded to "32767".

However, when it going to work with `EXPAND_AND_STRINGIFY(SHRT_MIN)`, it will be expanded to "(-32767 -1)", because `#define SHRT_MIN (-SHRT_MAX - 1)`. This is not what I want. Is there any possible workarounds for it?

Comment: What do you want SHRT_MIN to be expanded into?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::to_string`. What is "the string parser". And so on.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to get a preprocessor macro to *evaluate* an arithmetic expression.

You can get the preprocessor to do arithmetic evaluate, but only in the context of `#if`, which allows you to evaluate a boolean expression. You can use that feature to rather laboriously output a number, but only by using preprocessor input in `#include`d files, since you cannot put `#if` inside a macro.

You don't mention *why* you want to stringify `INT_MIN`, so I'm not in a position to offer an alternative, if indeed one exists.

However, it's most likely that your best bet is to simply produce the string at run-time, using `snprintf`.